# program stops after execvp( command.argv[0], command.argv)

Tags: c++, operating-system, execvp

I am writing a small shell program that takes a command and executes it.  If the user enters a not valid command the if statement returns a -1.  If the command is correct it executes the command, however once it executes the command the program ends.  What am I doing wrong that is does not execute the lines of code after it?  I have tested execvp( command.argv[0], command.argv) with ls and cat commands so I am pretty sure it works.  Here is my code.

```
  int shell(char *cmd_str ){
  int commandLength=0;
  cmd_t command;
  commandLength=make_cmd(cmd_str,  command);
  cout<< commandLength<<endl;
  cout << command.argv[0]<< endl;
  if( execvp( command.argv[0], command.argv)==-1)
//if the command it executed nothing runs after this line
  {
    commandLength=-1;

}else
{
  cout<<"work"<<endl;
}

  cout<< commandLength<<endl;
   return commandLength;


}
```

Comment: That is exactly how the `exec*` functions are supposed to work! They load the new program and _replace_ your program with the new one.

Comment: @Aaron: You would expect airplanes pilots to at least **read the manual** of the plane they want to "work on". Why don't you have the same expectations about you as a programmer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) of `execvp(3)`

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with
>   a new process image

So your current process image is overwritten with the image of your command! Hence you need to use a `fork+exec` combination always so that your command executes in the child process and your current process continues safely as a parent!

On a lighter note I want to illustrate the problem with a picture as *a picture speaks a thousand words*. No offence intended :) :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. The functions described in this manual page are front-ends for execve(2). (See the manual page for > execve(2) for further details about the replacement of the current process image.)

If you want your process to continue, this is not the function you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

@Pavan - Just for nit-pickers like myself, technically the statement "current process is gone" is not true. It's still the same process, with the same pid, just overwritten with a different image (code, data etc).

Comment: This should probably be made as a comment to @Pavan's question, or made a complete and correct answer.

Comment: English is a phunny language you know :) I rephrased my answer.

Comment: @crashmstr: I think that this guy is below the comment threshold.

Comment: Indeed, this guy is below the comment threshold and can only comment on his own answers like this one.